# Capitalizing the first character of a string - Java

Tags: java

I've looked all over for how to capitalize the first character of a string, but nothing I've found has helped.  For my method to work, I need to set a user entered string to lower case.

```
sourceText = enterText.getText();
char chr = sourceText.charAt(0);
```

so I have a boolean that's true if the first character is uppercase.

```
boolean upperCase = Character.isUpperCase(chr);
sourceTextLower = sourceText.toLowerCase();
```

Cool stuff happens here, and the final product is another string called translatedTextString and an if statement

```
String s2 = "";
if(upperCase == true)
{
    int x = translatedTextString.length();
    s2 = translatedTextString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(translatedTextString.substring(1, x));
}

//translatedText is a label
translatedText.setText(s2);
```

However, when I run the program, the first character of my result is still lower case.  So my questions is: is this even the right way to go about doing this? If so, what am I doing wrong, and if not, how can I do it correctly?

Comment: see my answer below for a simpler solution, but I think the problem in your code is that you need to test `if (upperCase == false)` for your code to work. Otherwise you are just capitalizing a string that is already capitalised, which won't do you much good :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be easier just to *assume* that the first letter is always lowercase, then you don't need any checks:

```
String s         = "some string";
String capitol   = Character.toString(s.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
String newString = capitol + s.substring(1,x);
```

Comment: OH!!! I found the problem.  First of all, what you posted helped a lot and was a lot nicer looking than what I was trying, thanks.  Turns out there was somehow some mystery whitespace as the first character of the string I was trying to capitalize, so it was trying to capitalize whitespace.

Comment: Turning whitespace into Whitespace?  :-)

Comment: @user1179374 If you have trouble with leading or trailing whitespace have a look at the `trim()` function of the String class API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do it as follows, using the [Character.toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) function on the first character of the string:

```
String s ="hello world";
String capitalized = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your code correctly, you're changing it to uppercase, when upperCase = true? So the lower case ones wont trigger that flag, and you wont make anything upperCase...

should be

```
if(!upperCase)
```

Comment: if I do that, it will just skip over the if statement.  When the first character of the sourceText string is capital, the boolean upperCase is true.  I want the first character of translatedTextString to be capital if the first character of the sourceText string is capital.

Comment: It will skip over the if statement if the first letter is uppercase only... which is what you want, you want it to only do the if statement when the first letter is lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this complete code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class captalizeCharactor {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int a1, a2;
    char ch1, ch2;
    String str;
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    str = in.readLine();
    ch1 = str.charAt(0);
    sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    a1 = ch1;
    if(a1>=97 || a1<=122){
        a2 = a1 - 97;
        ch2 = (char) (65+a2) ;
        sb.setCharAt(0, ch2);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html

or

```
String source = "hello good old world";
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

String[] strArr = source.split(" ");
for (String str : strArr) {
    char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
    stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
    str = new String(stringArray);

    res.append(str).append(" ");
}

System.out.print("Result: " + res.toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this complete code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CapitalizeFirstCharacter
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = input.next();

        StringBuilder wordTemp = new StringBuilder(word);
        char firstCharacter = wordTemp.charAt(0);

        if(firstCharacter>=97 && firstCharacter<=122)
        {
            firstCharacter -= 32;
            wordTemp.setCharAt(0, firstCharacter);
        }

        System.out.println(wordTemp.toString());
    }
}
```